# SqlTableDependency permission issue with the Active Directory group

Tags: sql-server

I implemented the SqlTableDependency in C#. Everything was working fine with the individual userId - which was granted as db_owner but I was told that the individual IDs are not allowed to create in QA/PROD environment and should use the ACTIVE Directory login 'Domain/AD_GP_NAME'.

I am then assigned to this group and this group also is not allowed to set to db owner. This group is added as a login in SQL DB. From C# code I am using 'Integerated security= SSPI' in connection string and on running SQL Profiler instead of domain\AD_GP_Name it shows my windows ID and on _dependency.start()

I am getting below error: 
An entity of type service cannot be owned by a role, a group, or by principals mapped to certificates or asymmetric keys

I tried various help links such as checking the schema assigned to this group which is 'dbo'. Also checked on assigning the

```
GRANT CREATE QUEUE to [domain\AD_GP_Name]
GRANT CREATE SERVICE to [domain\AD_GP_Name]

GRANT SELECT to [domain\AD_GP_Name] 
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO [domain\AD_GP_Name] 
GRANT RECEIVE ON QueryNotificationErrorsQueue TO [domain\AD_GP_Name] 

GRANT REFERENCES on 
CONTRACT::[http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]
  to [domain\AD_GP_Name] 
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [domain\AD_GP_Name]
```

but none of this solution resolved the problem. Please advise.